# Navigation doesn't render properly when web site is host in remote server wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have used following html and css code for the word press navigation. When I run the web site in all major browsers, website's navigation render properly.

But when I host it in remote server and run the web I see navigation is not perfectly set as it is in local only in IE browser.

I can't exactly guess, where I have to fix.

Here is my code.

```
#access {
    /*background: #6AA666;*/
    color: #1982D1;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    float: left;
    margin-top:-6px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:#d2e1fc;

  float:left;

  margin-left:-20px;

  text-align:center;
  width:104%;



}
```

php code

```
<nav id="access" role="navigation">
            <h3 class="assistive-text"><?php _e( 'Main menu', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></h3>
            <?php /* Allow screen readers / text browsers to skip the navigation menu and get right to the good stuff. */ ?>
            <div class="skip-link"><a class="assistive-text" href="#content" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Skip to primary content', 'twentyeleven' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Skip to primary content', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></a></div>
            <div class="skip-link"><a class="assistive-text" href="#secondary" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Skip to secondary content', 'twentyeleven' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Skip to secondary content', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></a></div>
            <?php /* Our navigation menu. If one isn't filled out, wp_nav_menu falls back to wp_page_menu. The menu assigned to the primary location is the one used. If one isn't assigned, the menu with the lowest ID is used. */ ?>
            <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
            <div id="logo" style="float:right;width:150px; margin-top:10px;"></div>
        </nav><!-- #access -->
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgakQ.png
navigation is not align properly at the left corner

Comment: What does it mean "navigation is not perfectly set"?

Answer (score 0):

giving specific height and width for banners I could solve the above issue